# Ninject InRequestScope for non-web projects

Tags: c#, ninject

My application is a micro-service that reads from a queue and processes messages.  It has no WebAPI component.

Each message must have it's own set of concrete instances, as configured by the DI setup.  e.g. Dbcontext is per message, but the application may process several message simultaneously on different tasks, so each message must have a different DbContext.

The message parser creates a new Ninject block for each message, and calls it asynchronously, like this:

```
using (var block = _kernel.BeginBlock())
{
    var processorInstance = block.Get(processor.MessageProcessorType);

    await processor.CallMessageProcessorAsync(processorInstance, messageBodyBase)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

How do I configure Ninject to provide 'scoped' object instances?  I realise there is a package called `InRequestScope` but that is for WebApi projects, which mine isn't.

Comment: this should help https://mono.software/2016/04/21/Ninject-ambient-scope-and-deterministic-dispose/ especially the part "AmbientScope in .NET 4.6"

Comment: Would it be possible to create a new thread for processing each new message and use `InThreadScope`?